# Channel Form / Transcribe Required Field Error

Tags: safecracker, transcribe

We have the following issue:

**Description of the problem**
We have a channel form script that submitted correct in ee3.5.8, but upon upgrade to ee5.2.6 we now get a required field error.

Transcribe module is installed, we have tried completely disabling the module and the error persists.

**Error Messages**

With JSON parameter set to 'yes' (in the channel form script and with the assigned Ajax script disabled) we get:

```
{"success":0,"errors":[],"field_errors":{"transcribe__transcribe_language":"This field is required."},"entry_id":3390,"url_title":"2stabilise-as","channel_id":4}
```

With JSON parameter set to 'no' (in the channel form script) we get:

```
The form you submitted contained the following errors

    Language Association: This field is required.
```

**Environment Details:**
 - Version: 5.2.6
 - PHP Version 7.0.33
 - MySQL Version 5.6
 - OS: macOS
 - Web Server: Apache

**Template Code**

The channel form code:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="directory" 
    return = "members/profile/updated"
    entry_id = "3390" 
    json = "no"
    id = "cform"
    class="form-horizontal"
    include_jquery="no"
    include_assets="no"
}

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        {if "{embed:is_admin}"=="true"}
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" size="50" maxlength="100" class="form-control input-lg">
        {if:else}
            <input type="text" value="{title}" class="form-control input-lg" disabled>
            <span class="text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        {/if}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="url_title" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><a href="{path="members/details"}/{url_title}" target="_blank" title="See your directory listing&hellip;"><span class="fa fa-external-link"></span> Link</a></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        {if "{embed:is_admin}"=="true"}
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">{path="members/details"}</span>
                <input type="text" name="url_title" id="url_title" value="{url_title}" maxlength="75" size="50" class="form-control">
            </div>
        {if:else}
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">{path="members/details"}/</span>
                <input type="text" disabled value="{url_title}" class="form-control">
                <span class="text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
        {/if}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="member_email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Website</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" name="member_url" id="member_url" value="{member_url}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="member_email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" name="member_email" id="member_email" value="{member_email}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="technical_authority" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Technical Authority</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        {if "{embed:is_admin}"=="true"}
                <input type="text" name="technical_authority" id="technical_authority" value="{technical_authority}" class="form-control input-lg">
        {if:else}
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" disabled value="{technical_authority}" class="form-control input-lg">
                <span class="text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
        {/if}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <p class="help-block">The name of the Technical Authority</p>
        </div>
    </div>



<fieldset{if "{embed:is_admin}" == "false"} disabled{/if}>
    <legend>{exp:transcribe:translate name="address"}Address{/exp:transcribe:translate}:</legend>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="member_address_1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Line 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        {if "{embed:is_admin}"=="true"}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_address_1" id="member_address_1" value="{member_address_1}">
        {if:else}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" diabled placeholder="{member_address_1}">
            <span class="text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        {/if}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="member_address_2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Line 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        {if "{embed:is_admin}"=="true"}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_address_2" id="member_address_2" value="{member_address_2}">
        {if:else}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" diabled placeholder="{member_address_2}">
            <span class="text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        {/if}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="member_address_3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Line 3</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        {if "{embed:is_admin}"=="true"}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_address_3" id="member_address_3" value="{member_address_3}">
        {if:else}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" diabled placeholder="{member_address_3}">
            <span class="text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        {/if}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="member_address_4" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Line 4</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        {if "{embed:is_admin}"=="true"}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_address_4" id="member_address_4" value="{member_address_4}">
        {if:else}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" diabled placeholder="{member_address_4}">
            <span class="text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        {/if}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="member_address_city" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        {if "{embed:is_admin}"=="true"}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_address_city" id="member_address_city" value="{member_address_city}">
        {if:else}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" diabled placeholder="{member_address_city}">
            <span class="text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        {/if}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="member_address_county" class="col-sm-2 control-label">County</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        {if "{embed:is_admin}"=="true"}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_address_county" id="member_address_county" value="{member_address_county}">
        {if:else}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" diabled placeholder="{member_address_county}">
            <span class="text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        {/if}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="member_country" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        {if "{embed:is_admin}"=="true"}
            {exp:reegion_select:countries name="member_country" id="member_country" selected="{member_country}{region_alpha2}{/member_country}" class="form-control" type="alpha2"}
        {if:else}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" diabled placeholder="{member_country}{region_name}{/member_country}">
            <span class="text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        {/if}
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>



    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="member_map" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Map</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {!--field:member_map--}
            <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:16em"></div>
            <input name="member_map" id="member_map" value="{member_map}" type="hidden">
            <input id="places_search" class="form-control" placeholder="Town/City Zoom">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" style="padding:0 15px">
        <label for="member_description">Description</label>
        {field:member_description}
        {!--
        <div class="tinymce" name="member_description" id="member_description">{member_description}</div>
        --}
    </div>


{!--

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="member_image" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Logo/Image</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign hidden form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>

{member_image}File name: {file_name}{/member_image}
<input type="file" name="member_image" class="form-control" />
<input type="hidden" name="member_image_hidden_file" value="{member_image}{file_name}{/member_image}" />
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">Browse&hellip; 
                        <input type="file" name="member_image" id="member_image">
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input id="member_image_hidden_file" type="text" readonly name="member_image_hidden_file" class="form-control" value="{member_image}{file_name}{/member_image}">
            </div><!-- /input-group -->

            <button id="remove-img" type="button" class="close{if !member_image} hidden{/if}" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

            <span id="list">
            {if !member_image}Select a file to upload
            {if:else}
                {member_image}<label for="member_image"><img class="thumb img-responsive" src="{url}" title="{file_name}"></label>{/member_image}
            {/if}
            </span>
            <input type="hidden" name="member_image_directory" value="9">
        </div>
    </div>
--}


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="control-label" for="categories_1" >Services</label>
            <select name="category[]" id="categories_1" multiple class="form-control selectpicker">
            {categories show_group="2"}
              <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
            {/categories}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        {if "{embed:is_admin}"=="true"}
            <label class="control-label" for="categories_2">Region</label>
            <select name="category[]" id="categories_2" multiple class="form-control selectpicker">
            {categories show_group="3"}
              <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
            {/categories}
            </select>
        {if:else}
            <label class="control-label">Region <span class="text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></label>
            <input type="text" value="{categories show_group='3' backspace='6'}{if selected}{category_name}, {/if}{/categories}" class="form-control input-lg" disabled>
        {!-- DANGER. only hidden by css! --}
            <select name="category[]" multiple="multiple" class="hidden">
            {categories show_group="3"}
            <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{!--category_name--}</option>
            {/categories}
            </select>
        {/if}
        </div>
    </div>

    {if in_group_1_6}
    <hr>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="well bg-danger">
            <h4>Admin Only <span class="fa fa-lock"></span></h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="control-label" for="categories_3" >Type</label>
                    <select name="category[]" id="categories_3" multiple
                     class="form-control selectpicker">
                    {categories show_group="1"}
                    <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
                    {/categories}
                    </select>

{!-- ADDS RAC CATEGORY GROUP --}                    
                    <label class="control-label" for="categories_3b" >RAC</label>
                    <select name="category[]" id="categories_3b" class="form-control selectpicker">
                    {categories show_group="15"}
                    <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
                    {/categories}
                    </select>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {if:else}
        {!-- DANGER. only hidden by css! --}
        <select name="category[]" multiple="multiple" class="hidden">
        {categories show_group="1"}
        <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{!--category_name--}</option>
        {/categories}
        </select>
    {/if}

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div id="success" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible hidden" role="alert" data-hide="3000">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Success!</strong> This directory entry has been updated. <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="error" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible hidden" role="alert" data-hide="3000">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <span class="message"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>


{/exp:channel:form}
```

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Many thanks in advance :-)

Kind Regards

Karl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a hidden field called transcribe__transcribe_language and set it to {transcribe:language_abbreviation}

Or you can try to add: transcribe="disable" to your channel form tag

Comment: Hi Jelle, many thanks for the feedback on this.

I did try the parameter transcribe="disable" in the channel form tag but this does not work.

I've also tried adding the hidden field:  '<input type="hidden" transcribe__transcribe_language="{transcribe:language_abbreviation}" value="1" />' but this didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Further update on this: I have tried this line and it's worked!

`<input type="hidden" name="transcribe__transcribe_language" value="{exp:transcribe:entries}{transcribe_entry_lang_id}{/exp:transcribe:entries}" />`

Comment: Many thanks once again for this, much appreciated :-)